# C# Winforms DatagridView conditional color for negative cell in named column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

On the web, there are plenty of things and their contrary about the topic.

I have a datagridview and I simply want to apply a green/red forecolor in function of the cell's value of a particular column called "YTD".
Here is my code:

```
dataGridViewEquity.Columns["YTD"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "[Green]0.00;[Red]-0.00;[Blue]zero";
```

UPDATE

Here is the first part of the Event handler I'm trying to build:

```
public void DataGridViewEquity_CellFormatting(object sender,DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (dataGridViewEquity.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("YTD"))
        {
            Decimal intValue;
            if (intValue < 0)
            {
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

    }
```

output:

```
[Red]-3,90
```

instead of -3,90 in red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

You have to add some checks:

- The current Row Index is `>= 0` and is not `[DataGridView].NewRowIndex`: you get an exceptions if you try to set a Cell value when these conditions are not met (the Row Index check here may not be needed, let's add it anyway).
- Since you have a DataSource, also check for both `null` and `DBNull.Value`: you get an exception if you try to cast the Cell value in this case (and of course there's nothing to format).

---

```
private void DataGridViewEquity_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs  e)
{
    var dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dgv.NewRowIndex) return;

    var cell = dgv["YTD", e.RowIndex];
    if (cell.Value == null || cell.Value == DBNull.Value) return;

    decimal value = (decimal)cell.Value;
    cell.Style.ForeColor = value == 0 ? Color.Blue : value < 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
}
```

If the Cell's Value is numeric, you could also write:

```
var value = (dynamic)cell.Value;
```

You should also set the Format of the `YTD` Column to 2 decimal places, in case you haven't done this yet. Add this right after the `DataGridViewEquity.DataSource` has been set:

```
DataGridViewEquity.Columns["YTD"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I understand better now ! a thing stays weird to me : DatagridView["column", e.RowIndex]. But I assume it links with he fact that I barel deal with the "e", I don't see the value behind this "e" . That results in the fact that  I understand your logic and the algo you proposed but I don't know how to trigger this DataGridViewEquity_CellFormatting event

Comment: thanks a lot ! I understand it better now ! In fact the event wasn't suscribed for some reason, I needed to suscribre it directly in within the form